# Не могу отправить изменения из-за старого пользователя git

Tags: git, github

Клонировал личный проект на рабочий ноут (macos) (до этого ноут был у моего товарища, вроде все удалил своё), но при push выдает отказ в доступе и ссылается на товарища

```
remote: Permission to   (name of project) denied to (old user).
fatal: unable to access (name of project): The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот это помогло !

1. Откройте файл .git/config в директории вашего локального репозитория
2. Найдите там запись url= под секцией [remote "origin"]
3. Поменяйте ее с (например) url=https://PetyaIvanov@github.com/petyaivanov/test_test.git на url=ssh://git@github.com/petyaivanov/test_test.git (ssh-ключ к вашему репо можно найти на самом гитхабе)
4. Сохраните и закройте файл конфига. Теперь можете попробовать git push origin master